# Timeout Exception with Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

Which specific exception could i catch in case Spring Data Jpa repository query gets timeout ?

Lets say that i have repository like this one:

```
public interface VoucherRepository extends CrudRepository<VoucherEntity, String> {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true, timeout = 30)
    VoucherEntity findByCode(String code);

    List<VoucherEntity> findAllByCodeIn(List<String> codes);
}
```

Which exception would be seen by caller when timeout happens ?

I don't know how to simulate this scenario, bonus question would be how to do that?

Used database is PostrgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception you would get is `QueryTimeoutException` which is a subclass of the `DataAccessException`, which is the generic *"something went wrong while using Spring to access a DB"*.

Answer (score 4):

If you have configured

```
 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />
```

From Spring Documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances

> Using this element looks up Spring Data repositories as described in
>   Creating repository instances. Beyond that it activates persistence
>   exception translation for all beans annotated with @Repository to let
>   exceptions being thrown by the JPA persistence providers be converted
>   into Spring’s DataAccessException hierarchy.

So you can catch DataAccessException to handle your exceptions

Answer (score 1):

While using Spring's @Transactional timeout, you will get "org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException" exception.

Actually you could simulate the situation by locking a table during the test like given below.

```
LOCK TABLE table_name IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

Make sure that the transaction is not complete until you complete the testing and the end the transaction to release the lock on the table.

Comment: If the database isn't responding at all, the exception thrown is `org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException` when using transactions